# Electric led lights kitchen ceiling replacement

Tags: light-fixture, kitchens

[image]These are lights in my kitchen ceiling track lights fixture. I want to have daylight

I am okay if the round shape has less bulbs - instead of 5 even 3 is okay

They connect to electricity by this pin that is hanging from my track lights fixture [image]

The text along the edge says ep111902. Is there any way to get a replacement?
What are they called?

Update 1-----------------------
I noticed that i can remove the black dial/circle very easily. Therefore interested in replacing the black dial/circle with the lights that are day light. I would appreciate if anyone can post a link to purchase.
I live in Arizona USA and these were installed by the previous owner so dont know where they were bought

Comment: those LEDs look good to me, usually when they "burn out", there's a discoloration or darkening on the yellow part. I suspect it's the medium-voltage driver on the other side of the red and blue wires that has failed. That said, those are usually bespoke, so replacing the whole unit is likely the most cost-effective/simplest solution.

Comment: LEDs are working fine. I just want to replace them with day light. I would appreciate if you can share a link where i could buy those

Comment: Please answer update 1 if possible

Comment: "Share a link where I could buy those" is _firmly_ in "shopping recommendations" territory, which is _explicitly_ [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). "Is there a way to get a replacement" was pretty close to off-topic as "shopping" and would have gotten my VtC too. Unfortunately, the question cannot be closed now that there's a bounty on it, but you're not going to get someone to provide a link to Amazon or AliBaba with a "here, buy this" recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this kind of lamp, the expectation is that you would replace the whole fixture, not the circuit board.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But what are those lights called?

Comment: You select whatever you like. There is no replacement unless you know where they were purchased.

Comment: Those light are made specifically for the fixture. They are not standard and are not available for purchase separately.

Comment: It is probably possible to get something that would work, in OEM quantities, through OEM purchase channels, shipped from whatever country they're made in; if you pay a bit more you might even be able to get a circuit board that would _probably_ pass UL testing (UL doesn't test components, only complete devices). But these days you really are expected to treat the whole bulbless fixture as disposable; they make it cost less by not making it customer-repairable.

Answer (score 2):

It's some sort of knockoff of a "star" LED board. That's typically a metal-core board for heat dissipation reasons specific to high-power LEDs.

Problem being, while you can find non-knockoff star or cluster LED boards, (in non-industrial quantities, even, from domestic suppliers, even) you will have to find ones compatible with your unknown LED driver (presumably at the far end of the red and blue wires.) Or you have to replace the driver with a compatible driver, and at that point, you'll probably have exceeded the price of a whole new fixture.

In any case, shopping questions (which your update firmly converts this to) are strictly off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

What are you willing to spend on this? There are flashlight modders out there that'll reflow leds as a service, but after a bit of back and forth establishing voltage, time and effort to order leds (if they exist in daylight temp), actual reflow, testing, plus shipping and handling, you're destined to be into a few benjamins.

Maybe think about a new fixture, or at least doing a bit of research (voltage, current) to figure out if a new fixture could be plundered for parts for your old fixture.